# Selecting tests from the middle of a test lab in QC

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vbscript, hp-quality-center

I am having around 800 odd tests in QC. I have a vbscript that will run and mark all test cases in test lab as PASS when I run the script. The only worry is, the script always starts running from the first test until the last one which I specify (say from 1st test till 700th test or from 1st test till 140th test). I want to change the code so that I can run the script from the middle such as from 500th test to 600th or from 430th test to 450th test and so on. I tried editing all the possible values in my code but of no use. 
Can someone help me to crack it?

Posting code

```
Option Explicit

Dim j
Dim qcServer
Dim tdc
Dim testset
Dim TSetFact
Dim tsTreeMgr
Dim npath
Dim tsFolder
Dim tsList
Dim tSetName


qcServer = "http://testdirector.mot.com/qcbin"
'nPath = "Root\Execution\Build_1.0"
nPath = "Root\Execution\Build_1.0"
tSetName  = "Test Folder"


WScript.Echo qcserver

Set tdc = CreateObject("tdapiole80.tdconnection")

tdc.InitConnectionEx qcServer

tdc.Login "username", "password"

tdc.Connect "DEFAULT", "TEAMMate"

If tdc.ProjectConnected = True Then
WScript.Echo "Connected to the Project Columbus"
End If

WScript.Echo "Logged in ??"
WScript.Echo tdc.LoggedIn 
WScript.Echo "Connected ??"
WScript.Echo tdc.Connected 
WScript.Echo "Server name"
WScript.Echo tdc.ServerName 
WScript.Echo "Domain name"
WScript.Echo tdc.DomainName
WScript.Echo "Project name"
WScript.Echo tdc.ProjectName 
WScript.Echo "username"
WScript.Echo tdc.UserName 


Set TSetFact =  tdc.TestSetFactory
Set tsTreeMgr = tdc.TestSetTreeManager
Set tsFolder = tsTreeMgr.NodeByPath(nPath)

If tsFolder Is Nothing Then
WScript.Echo "Testset folder not found"
End If
WScript.Echo "Test set folder exists"

Set tsList = tsFolder.FindTestSets(tSetName)

If tsList Is Nothing Then
WScript.Echo "Testset not found"
End If

If tsList.Count > 1 Then
WScript.Echo "Multiple Testsets found with same name"
End If
If tsList.Count < 1 Then
WScript.Echo "Testset not found"
End If

WScript.Echo "Testset exists"
Set testset = tsList.Item(1)
WScript.Echo testSet.Name

Dim TSTestFact
Dim TestSetTestsList
Dim thetest



    Set TSTestFact = testSet.TSTestFactory
    Set TestSetTestsList = TSTestFact.NewList("")
    j = 0

    Dim sID
    Dim sName

    For Each thetest In TestSetTestsList
    j = j + 1 
    If j > 737 Then    **j > 737 indicates run up to 737th test in the test lab) **
    Exit For
    End If 
    'sID = thetest.ID
    sName = thetest.Name
    'WScript.Echo sID
    If j > 0 Then 
    WScript.Echo "testcase found for execution"
    Dim runName
    Dim RunF
    Dim theRun
    Dim runStepF
    Dim lst
    Dim Item
    Dim runtitle

    'Set runtitle = "Run"

    runName = thetest.ID
    Set RunF = thetest.RunFactory
    Set theRun = RunF.AddItem(runName)
    theRun.Status = "Passed"
    theRun.Post   

    theRun.CopyDesignSteps
    theRun.Post 

    Set runStepF = theRun.StepFactory
    Set lst = runStepF.NewList("")
    For Each Item In lst
     Item.Status = "Passed"
     Item.Post
    Next    
    End If     
    WScript.Echo sName
    Next

'Set ObjRun = QCUtil.CurrentRun
'Dim sf1 as StepFactory
'Dim s1 as step

'Set sf1 = ObjRun.StepFactory
'Set s1 = sf1.NewList("")

'For i = 1 To s1.count
's1.Item(i).Field("ST_EXPECTED") = "Your Expected"
's1.Item(i).Field("ST_ACTUAL") = "Your Actual"

'Next

's1.Post

'Disconnect
If tdc.Connected Then
tdc.Disconnect
WScript.Echo "Disconnected QC session successfully"
End If

'Log off the server
If tdc.LoggedIn Then
tdc.Logout
WScript.Echo "Logged off from the Server successfully"
End If

'Release the TDConnection object.
tdc.ReleaseConnection
WScript.Echo "Released the connection"
'Check status
Set tdc = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the code should work for test case number 737 or greater. Also check in Quality Center help for OTA references that may help. You can download both Mercury Quality Center *Open Test Architecture API Reference* (OTA_API_Reference.chm) & *Site Administration API Reference*  (Site_Admin_API_Reference.chm) file from here:
http://technologicaguru.blogspot.com.au/2008/03/quality-center-open-test-architecture.html

Without not having tried myself, at first glance you could try replacing part of the code with the following specifying a lower and upper test case number range to query:

```
Dim sID
Dim sName
Dim testCaseStart
Dim testCaseEnd
'Change testCaseStart and testCaseEnd to required test case range 
testStartVal = 500
testEndVal = 600

For Each thetest In TestSetTestsList
  If j >= testCaseStart And j <= testCaseEnd then 
    'sID = thetest.ID
    sName = thetest.Name
    'WScript.Echo sID
    If j > 0 Then 
      WScript.Echo "testcase found for execution"
      Dim runName
      Dim RunF
      Dim theRun
      Dim runStepF
      Dim lst
      Dim Item
      Dim runtitle

      'Set runtitle = "Run"

      runName = thetest.ID
      Set RunF = thetest.RunFactory
      Set theRun = RunF.AddItem(runName)
      theRun.Status = "Passed"
      theRun.Post   

      theRun.CopyDesignSteps
      theRun.Post 

      Set runStepF = theRun.StepFactory
      Set lst = runStepF.NewList("")
      For Each Item In lst
        Item.Status = "Passed"
        Item.Post
      Next    
    End If     
    WScript.Echo sName
  End If
  j = j + 1
Next
```